# Dyed and Sealed concrete - do I wax on a "sacrificial layer" to protect sealant?

Tags: concrete

Just removed old carpet and had the concrete dyed and sealed in our family room.      Before allowing anyone in there or moving furniture back in, I am vacillating between adding a "sacrificial" layer of wax (though I'd prefer not to glossy up the floors any further) or just plan to seal them again in a year or so if I am noticing scuffing?   I bought Lundmark All Wax (I can return) and would run out to home depot to get a appropriate mop head if needed.

I have read up some on how to clean the floors but also always happy for suggestions.
(I have two small dogs who weigh less than 18 pounds with small regularly maintained claws.) [image: Still curing sealed/dyed concrete-Surfkoat.com]

Comment: What does the person who did the concrete stain work recommend for protecting the newly-stained surface?

Comment: Very minimal commentary from the concrete guys - "not a bad idea" (when asking the same question in this post) and "home depot or ace has wax" (when asking for a wax recommendation for low shine/good for the concrete seal) so I was curious if others had commentary since the contractor was less than inspiring.

Comment: I'm surprised they didn't have recommendations, as I'd think they'd want the job to last and look good for a long time, so you'd recommend them to others.

Answer (score 1):

There are so-called ["low gloss" concrete floor waxes](https://www.concretesealersusa.com/ts206-acrylic-floor-wax-wb-w-low-gloss-1-gal/) available. The manufacturer of this example product describes is as a "matte finish".

It is recommended to seal the concrete floor to protect it from picking up stains and protecting against scuffing and scratching so you seem to be on the right track.

Comment: Yes, the "acrylic wax" products such as this were what came to mind immediately - they are called wax but are more of a finish that can be easily renewed or removed without taking off the finish below if needed for complete renewal. They are commonly seen in commercial settings. The only one I can think of that actively markets (though I can't say I've seen an ad for it in decades...) to home use is all about its shine, while matte products are commonly available. In either case, not actually slippery wax as one assumes "floor wax" to be if thinking about real wax.

Comment: Maybe talk to a commercial janitorial supply company in your town and see if they have products they'd recommend to protect the floor with a low sheen.